# Applying filter to PowerShell output

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

**Script.ps1**

```
aws rds --region us-east-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"
```

I am trying to apply filter to get only two outputs, Output1 and Output2

I want to filter the following.

**Output**

```
[
"db-global-company-sales-11.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-global-company-staging-104.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-logging-nebula-integration-10.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-tenant-02-nebula-dev-51.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-tenant-02-nebula-dev-50.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-tenant-company-sales-11.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-tenant-company-staging-104.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db-tenant-nebula-dev-51.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"neb-dev-51-db-global.xxxxxxus-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"neb-dev-50-db-global.xxxxxxus-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"nebula-redshift-2-postgres.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
]
```

**Desired output**

```
Output1: db-tenant-${ get values with the greatest integer - I want the latest update }
Output2: neb-dev-${ greatest integer - I want the latest update }
```

After filter is applied this is the expected result (greatest values).

```
"Output1":"db-tenant-02-nebula-dev-51.xxxxxus-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
"Output2":"neb-dev-51-db-global.xxxxxus-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: It looks like you're running the standard awscli within a PowerShell script. It would probably be more sensible to actually use [AWS PowerShell Tools](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) instead. You would then get native PowerShell scripting features.

Answer (score 1):

My go to for parsing json on the command line is jq - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

There are plenty of pages on the use of jq and I believe can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi,

i installed the jq, I am new to using powershell. Can you help with the code?